# openmap NullPointerException Error in osmtile could not obtain tile

Tags: r, openstreetmap

I am trying to plot a small rectangle of a map:

```
library(OpenStreetMap)

upper_left  <- c(47.413, 8.551);
lower_right <- c(47.417, 8.556);

map_osm  <- openmap(upper_left, lower_right, type = 'osm' );
plot(map_osm );
```

When I run that, the `openmap` function gives me the error *Error in osmtile(x%%nX, y, zoom, type) : could not obtain tile: 540 298 10*.

The documentation of `OpenStreetMap` seems to indicate that I need to add an API key. However, I am not sure how exactly I would do that (because I use `type='osm'`, not `type = url`) and I am also unclear where I'd get such an API key from.

Comment: Not too sure, but from the example shown in the documentation of `openmap`, the API key is required if you are trying to get a map from `mapbox`. The example key looks typically that of `mapbox`.

Comment: And on running your code, I get no error. and the map plots.

Comment: @Dhiraj, that's interesting, it certainly does not for me.

Comment: Wish I could help. `map_osm` is a list of 2 in my environment (tiles and bbox). My OpenStreetMap version is 0.3.4

Comment: I am getting the same error, with a `java.lang.NullPointerException` before that. My Version is 0.3.3.

Comment: That error disappeared for me with version 0.3.4.

Comment: @SeGa: I installed a newer R version and then installed OpenStreetMap and now it's working. Thanks for the hint. You might want to turn the comment into an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I fixed the title since it has nothing to do with your problem. To answer you original question: You don't need an API key for accessing official OSM tile servers. However you (or the library you are using) need to respect [OSM's tile usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/). Alternatively you have to switch to a different tile server, for example MapBox.

Comment: @scai I specifically chose the title because that was what I was googling for before I asked the question on SO and what I was lead to believe was the reason for the problem I had.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger I understand. However if other people search for "Do I need to add an API key for OpenStreetMap" then they will find a matching question without a matching answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `java.lang.NullPointerException` and the following R-error (`Error in osmtile(...)`) seem to come from an older version of `OpenStreetMap`.

By updating `OpenStreetMap` to the latest version (**0.3.4** currently), the error disappears and the example code of OP should work as it is, without needing an API key.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not adequate as the error can occur even with the most recent package version.

Sometimes if a particular area is not available in a specific style, you get an error similar to the one mentioned above independent of the package version. The solution would be to try the function with a different style. This is mentioned in the following blog [post](https://josephcrispell.github.io/2019/07/20/openstreetmaps.html)

As an example, the following modification may solve the issue:

```
library(OpenStreetMap)

upper_left  <- c(47.413, 8.551);
lower_right <- c(47.417, 8.556);

map_osm  <- openmap(upper_left, lower_right, type = 'opencyclemap');
plot(map_osm)
```